# e.preventdefault() isn't working with react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to disable the page reload after submit a form in react using react-hook-form, however even using the e.preventDefault() the page reload. I tried to found something in the official docs but they just say to use the e param

```
import { useRef } from "react"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

function NewItemModal() {

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm()

  function handleAddNewItem(data: Object, e?: Event) {
    e?.preventDefault()
    console.log(data)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit((e) => handleAddNewItem(e))} className="space-y-8">
        <div className='grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-2 place-items-center gap-y-6'>
          <label className='space-y-1'>
            <h4>ID:</h4>
            <motion.input whileFocus={{ borderColor: '#FF9400' }} type="text" className='border border-raisin rounded indent-1 outline-none'
              {...register('item_id')} />
          </label>
          <div></div>
          <label className='space-y-1'>
            <h4>Nome:</h4>
            <motion.input whileFocus={{ borderColor: '#FF9400' }} type="text" className='border border-raisin rounded indent-1 outline-none'
              {...register('name')} />
          </label>
          <label className='space-y-1'>
            <h4>Condição:</h4>
            <motion.input whileFocus={{ borderColor: '#FF9400' }} type="text" className='border border-raisin rounded indent-1 outline-none'
              {...register('condition')} />
          </label>
          <label className='space-y-1'>
            <h4>Marca:</h4>
            <motion.input whileFocus={{ borderColor: '#FF9400' }} type="text" className='border border-raisin rounded indent-1 outline-none'
              {...register('brand')} />
          </label>
          <label className='space-y-1'>
            <h4>Setor:</h4>
            <motion.input whileFocus={{ borderColor: '#FF9400' }} type="text" className='border border-raisin rounded indent-1 outline-none'
              {...register('sector')} />
          </label>
          <label className='space-y-1'>
            <h4>Comodatário:</h4>
            <motion.input whileFocus={{ borderColor: '#FF9400' }} type="text" className='border border-raisin rounded indent-1 outline-none'
              {...register('borrower')} />
          </label>
          <label className='space-y-1'>
            <h4>Data:</h4>
            <motion.input whileFocus={{ borderColor: '#FF9400' }} type="text" className='border border-raisin rounded indent-1 outline-none'
              {...register('borrowerDate')} />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className='px-4 py-1 space-y-6 flex flex-col'>
          <label className='space-y-3 flex flex-col items-center'>
            <h4 className="self-start">Descrição:</h4>
            <motion.textarea whileFocus={{ borderColor: '#FF9400' }} className='p-2 w-full h-56 outline-none border border-raisin rounded text-sm'></motion.textarea>
          </label>
          <div className='flex justify-end'>
            <motion.button whileHover={{ scale: 1.03 }} type="submit" className="bg-princeton px-2 w-20 h-8 rounded border-2 border-raisin">
              Enviar
            </motion.button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default NewItemModal
```

How can i resolve this? I already tried to pass the event but it doesn't work

Comment: It seems your `handleAddNewItem` function receives two parameters, but you're only passing one, which corresponds to the data object. You try doing `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleAddNewItem)}

Comment: May I ask you whether there is any particular reason for putting `event.preventDefault()` into the `handleAddNewItem()` function? Logically, it should be inside the `handleSubmit()` function (at the very beginning). Furthermore, shouldn't the anonymous function you pass to the `onSubmit` attribute accept the `e` (event) argument, in order to pass it to the  `handleSubmit()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should directly pass the return value of `handleSubmit` to `onSubmit`, without wrapping it in another arrow function. There is then no need to call `event.preventDefault()` manually.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleAddNewItem)}>
```